# Getting byte sequence win1252 error while dumping data into posgresql using cmd using data.dump file

Tags: postgresql, encoding, utf-8

While loading the `data.dump` file using `cmd` from my local to my db in *PostgreSQL*, I'm getting this error

```
C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\bin>psql -U postgres -d sqlda -f D:\data.dump
```

> ```
> Password for user postgres:
> psql:D:/data.dump:1225: ERROR:  character with byte sequence 0x8f in encoding "WIN1252" has no equivalent in encoding "UTF8"
> psql:D:/data.dump:1300: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "2020"
> ```

Comment: Which part of the error message do you not understand? Look at the offending data. Maybe if you can tell us what result you expect, you can [edit] your question to clarify it, ideally with the offending data and the expected result as well as an explanation of how to reasonably get to there from here.

Comment: To above I would add; What version of pg_dump was used? , What version of Postgres was the database being dumped, What OS was the database being dumped on? In psql in the cluster you are dumping to what does show lc_collate; and show lc_ctype; return? Same for the cluster you are dumping from?